# how can i get the results of Prolog by searching a query through python

Tags: python, prolog

**This is the program which i have tried:**

```
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()
prolog.assertz("father(michael,john)")
prolog.assertz("father(michael,gina)")
print  list(prolog.query("father(michael,X)"))
```

**Output which i am getting:**
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

**Expected Output:**
X=gina

Answer (score 0):

You should just use

```
print(list(prolog.query("father(michael,X)")))
```